# Birt and POJO Datasource

Tags: birt

I want to create a BIRT report using the POJO Data Source. At this, I have do set the path to my .jar files. During development this is no problem because I have my .jar files in the `target` folder

However when I build my project, I will create an .ear file. How should I then locate the .jar file?

Answer (score 2):

You should delete classpath from rptdesign file. Classpath is defined in 2 places. You can find it here:

```
        <oda-data-source extensionID="org.eclipse.birt.data.oda.pojo" name="Data Source" id="132">
            <list-property name="privateDriverProperties">
                <ex-property>
                    <name>SynchronizeClassPath</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </ex-property>
                <ex-property>
                    <name>pojoClassPath</name>
                    <value></value>
                </ex-property>
            </list-property>
            <property name="pojoDataSetClassPath"></property>
        </oda-data-source>
```

Comment: This should be BOLD in the official documentation!